# Distribute iothub message to all partition

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub, azure-eventhub

**Introduction**
we have Device to cloud scenario(device->iothub) where at sometime the device can't have internet connection. It will store the message in the internal flash storage. After it gain the connection back it will burst of all of the message from the flash storage.

**Problem**
when **a single device** burst all of the message from the flash storage, the message will pileup in a particular partition.

for example, 
**below we have 220K message sent from a single device**
[220K Message from a device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XZSU7.png)

it flooded partition number 17.
seems like somehow this device always send message to partition 17.
[Message flooded single partition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AkOrs.png)

**question**
How we can distribute the message in across all partition that available @ Azure Iothub
*we have 32 partition enabled.

Comment: Could you describe a consumer side of the IoT Hub? What are you using? Is that a Stream Analytics job, etc.?

Comment: hi roman, appreciate the answer.
we use .NET that hosted @ azure cloud service to retrieve the data from iothub

Answer (score 1):

**The IoT Hub does not allow arbitrary partitioning**. Device-to-cloud messages are partitioned based on their originating deviceId. - see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-messages-construct).

The following are alternatives for delivery a large batch file from the device:

- [Upload file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-file-upload)
- [Device Streams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-device-streams-overview) (preview)

the other option is to route this batch message to the custom endpoint such as a Blob Storage, Event Hub, Event Grid, etc.

Comment: hi roman, 
currently we use .NET that hosted in cloudservice to retrieve the data from iothub,
do you think by having stream analytics can significantly increase the performance the "data pulling" ?
currently, when the partition pileup it delay the prioritized message

Comment: Are you consuming a telemetry data in the stream pipeline, ASA job (hot path)?

Comment: The IoT Hub telemetry data can be consumed as a single message or batches of messages. But in your scenario, when lots of telemetry data are stored temporary in the device storage (the device is disconnected for long time) is better to create a separate path for delivery their batch to the custom endpoint (or uploading) and then merge it to the main streaming pipeline. In other words, for short time when the device is disconnected and the temporary batch is small and there is no strictly the real-time requirements, the batch can be routed to the built-in default endpoint.

Comment: hi roman,
yes we plan to consuming the telemetry data in the stream pipeline.
we will try to explore the path separation for realtime required message and non-realtime required message.
i am assuming this separation will be done in iothub message routing right?
meaning, better if the device can flag which message should be prioritized.
If we plan to utilize this message routing, do you think it will impacting the iothub performance?

Comment: anyway, thanks much for the answer. really appreciate it :)

Comment: have a look at the IoT Hub limits and throttling https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-subscription-service-limits#iot-hub-limits and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-quotas-throttling